# Styling an input type="file" (text next to the button, not the button itself) using css

Tags: css

I'd like to style a regular input tag for file uploads.

I found many descriptions on how to style the button of the input ("choose file") using css. In my case I'd also like to style the text next to the button.

Here's the specific issue I'm working with:

All my buttons and inputs in this example are full-width. So should the file upload button.

How do I style the text next to the input file (e.g. other color and display: block, or any other styles to force a line break?)

[image]

```
.btn-secondary, input[type=file]::file-selector-button{
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  color: #333 !important;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-secondary:hover, input[type=file]::file-selector-button:hover{
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.btn-secondary:active, input[type=file]::file-selector-button:active{
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button{
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=file] *{
  display: block
}
```

Comment: So, you want a file upload functionality but you want it to look like an `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining correctly. 
I'd like to have it two lined. in this case "Choose File" and "No files selected" should be readable. The functionality should be like an `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limited support for styling the text label of `file` type input, but we can do a little hack:

```css
input[type=file] {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-style: oblique;
}
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="files.click()">Select Image</button>
<input type="file" id="files">
```

Comment: To hide the text altogether, one could set the ```input[type=file] { color: ###; }``` property to have the same color value as the container's ```background-color: ###;``` property.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this... In this case, I'm not styling the input. I'm not displaying it, but applying the functionality of it to another button.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=button] {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .5em 2em;
}

#myFileInput {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" id="myFileInput" />
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myFileInput').click()" value="Choose file" />
  <label for="myFileInput" class="label">No File Chosen</label>
</div>
```